# ember-cli "TypeError: desc.get is not a function" after upgrade of ember-cli

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

after updating ember-cli to v0.2.7 with ember v.1.12.0 I'm having some funny behavior that causes an exception when using computed properties.

Used model:

```
User = Ember.Object.extend
 md5: ""
 gravatar: (->
   return get_gravatar(@get("md5"))
   ).property("md5")
```

Calling `u.get("gravatar")` in the router, `afterModel` method, I get this:

```
u.get("gravatar")
ember.debug.js:15588 Uncaught TypeError: desc.get is not a function
    at Object.get (../vendor.js:26142:19)
    at exports.default.mixin.Mixin.create.get (../vendor.js:39811:27)
    at eval (eval at evaluate (unknown source), <anonymous>:1:3)
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateOn (<anonymous>:895:55)
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap (<anonymous>:828:34)
    at Object.InjectedScript.evaluateOnCallFrame (<anonymous>:954:21)
    at afterModel (../v4.js:3438:16)
    at applyHook (../vendor.js:55667:32)
    at Object.HandlerInfo.runSharedModelHook (../vendor.js:53668:22)
    at Object.HandlerInfo.runAfterModelHook (../vendor.js:53651:21)
```

When digging a bit deeper I saw that the error happens in `ember.debug.js at the getter function.

```
function get(obj, keyName) {
  ...
  if (desc) {
    return desc.get(obj, keyName); 
    // -> Error while processing route: recipe_edit desc.get is not a function TypeError: desc.get is not a function
   } else {
   ...
```

The type of `desc`was the same as when I called `u.gravatar` directly, so I'm not quite sure why this doesn't get resolved anymore.

```
desc: Object
  _cacheable: true
  _dependentKeys: Array[1]
  _readOnly: false
  isDescriptor: true
  __proto__: Object
```

Answer (score 0):

After some hours of debugging I figured out the problem myself. I have a serializer that resolves circular references and removes all unnecessary attributes from my Ember Object to convert it into a JSON.

In the previous Ember version it worked fine, but in this version somehow the recursive function worked its way through the Object into some Ember Framework code and **deleted functions from the Ember Framework during runtime**.

```
ComputedPropertyPrototype.volatile()
ComputedPropertyPrototype.property()
exports.default.mixin.Mixin.create.clear()
exports.default.mixin.Mixin.create.popObject()
exports.default.mixin.Mixin.create.shiftObject()
...
```

Therefore I got these weird sounding errors and difficult to debug errors, as the deletion of the property happens before it actually causes an error.

It was my bad with the hacky serializer, but I hope this helps some of you when stumbling upon the same error.